# Vuejs throws 400 (Bad Request) error on axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, koa

I have Nodejs on Port 5000 and Vuejs on port 8080. I'm using vue cli 3. Firstly I had a issue of CORS then i just fixed the issue of CORS by adding Koa-cors module. When i use koa restAPI in vuejs as a POST request. It throws error 400 (BAD REQUEST). Why it is coming? Is there any syntax issue with post request?

[image: Api Response]

RestAPI

```
import * as Koa from "koa";
import * as Router from "koa-router";
import * as koaBody from "koa-body";
import * as cors from "@koa/cors";


  const app = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  const PORT = 5000;

  app.use(cors());
  app.use(koaBody({multipart: true}));

  app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

      router.post('/api/admin_login', async (ctx: Koa.Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {

        var email = ctx.request.body.email;
        var password = ctx.request.body.password;

        const checkEmailExist = await Admin.findOne({email: email});
            if (checkEmailExist != null) {

                const pwCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, checkEmailExist.password);
                if (pwCorrect === true) {
                    ctx.body = {
                        status: 200,
                        message: "Admin login successfully",
                        data: checkEmailExist,
                    };
                } else {
                    ctx.body = {
                        status: 400,
                        message: "Incorrect password",
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ctx.body = {
                    status: 400,
                    message: "Invalid Email",
                };

            }
        }
    });
```

Vuejs Axios Post

```
 methods: {
            login() {
               const headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                };

                this.$axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/admin_login",
                    {
                        email: this.input.email,
                        password: this.input.password,
                    }, {
                        headers: headers
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('data', data);
                    });
               }
        }
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Take a look at the request body in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. It looks like you're sending JSON data with a `content-type` of `multipart/form-data`. Also, unrelated to the error, you shouldn't be setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the request: that's a response header, not a request header.